# How to install rastertoezpl on Pardus?

Tags: compiling, software-installation

I bought a barcode printer as Godex. I have to install its drivers. I did it on Ubuntu. However, I have some problems about it.For example:
In README file:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libcupsimage2-dev
```

But shell says me

`sudo:aptitude: command not found`

Moreover when i write `sudo apt-get install aptitude it` says

```
sudo:apt-get: command not found
```

And then,
When I write `./configure` shell says followings.

```
./configure

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

How can i fix it ? How can i install this package?
Thanks for your help already now.

Comment: [Pardus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardus_(operating_system)) is an independent Linux distribution, it is not *Debian-derived* and doesn't use the `apt` tool suite, i.e., no `apt-get` or `aptitude`.  It uses [its own package management, *"PiSi"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PiSi#PiSi_package_management).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Linux distribution (or family of distributions) has its own package management system. Ubuntu uses `.deb` packages and has the APT tool family including Aptitude. Pardus has its own package manager called [PiSi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardus_%28operating_system%29#PiSi_package_management).

Your immediate problem is “no acceptable C compiler”. You need to install a C compiler, and probably other development packages. See [“Compiling Software and Packaging”](http://en.pardus-wiki.org/HOWTO%3aContents#Compiling_Software_and_Packaging) in the Pardus Wiki; start by installing the basic development tools (the equivalent of Ubuntu's `build-essentials`):

```
sudo pisi install -c system.devel
```